# How to pull latest change from Gerrit repo

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a problem with pulling last commit changes from Gerrit server.
To push changes to the server I use git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master. So, I thought I can do similar for pull - git pull origin HEAD:refs/for/master, but it didn't work. In the meanwhile I found, that we need to use whole ssh address like eg. git pull "ssh://the/address/to/repo", but this solution didn't work either. I got an error: could't find remote ref HEAD
The only way I can pull the latest version is to open, on Gerrit server, last commit and to take the whole address with commit number. It looks like this, git pull "ssh://the/repo/address/" refs/changes/34/1234/1
Is it possible to pull changes without knowing last change number?

Comment: You may first try to learn how to copy/paste the output of the console when you perform a `git pull` command before trying to do it. Also read the output may lead you to a clue of why what you are trying to do doesn't work. (Protips, copy/paste the message into Google).

Comment: Thank you for your great help and helpfully answer. Do you think, that I'm asking questions without trying to solve the problem on my own or without searching a solution on google first?

Comment: I don't know what you have tried, you didn't write it in the OP. What I know and what I point is that you didn't make the effort to format your question to be readable. And this question had already been asked many times https://www.google.com/search?q=gerrit+pull+last+changed+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @torek has given a good answer and I'd like to supplement it. On the Gerrit change page, you could find the shortcut commands for checkout, cherry-pick, format-patch, pull and etc. They are basically a fetch command plus another verb. You could just copy and paste the corresponding commands.

Comment: I've been using copy paste from Gerrit. I thought only, that git pull will work like with other git implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Gerrit server, `refs/for/` is a "magic" name-space.

Gerrit is a Java implementation of a Git server, but it's *not Git*.<sup>1</sup>  It's a server implementation, and it does have a Git repository "behind" the server.  But the server accepts `git push` requests and shuttles them off for special processing, instead of putting new commits into the repository the way Git would.  Commits received for this special processing get a "change ID" assigned to them if they don't already have one: doing this assignment changes the commit to a different commit.

Once a commit (or series of commits) has a change ID assigned, *then* Gerrit puts those commits into a repository, under yet another name: neither your branch name, nor your `refs/for/branch` name, but rather a name based on the change-ID (plus a revision of that change ID).

To retrieve such a commit *from* a Gerrit server, you'll need to know the assigned name and the mapping.  That's your `refs/changes/34/1234/1` string.  If you don't know how Gerrit builds this string, and don't know what the change ID will be, you can't anticipate what it will be.

Hence:

> Is it possible to pull changes without knowing last change number?

No.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, technically, to say whether it is or is not Git, we'd have to define "Git".  For this particular answer's purpose, I'm defining "Git" as "software that implements the Git protocol *and* uses references exactly the way Git uses references".  It's the second half of this "and" that Gerrit violates—on purpose and for good reason and useful effect, but nonetheless, it violates it, so it's not Git.